# How can I read from a file in C programming?

Tags: c, string, file, file-io

I'm trying to read from a file in C programming, and I thought I did everything correctly but I am getting an error: "cannot open file ..." So it is clearly not accessing the file properly and I cannot figure out why. The file "A00924956Results2016" is in the same console application folder that my program file is in. So I shouldn't have to use file path right? Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I have simplified what I am trying to read, just so I can get it to access the file before I move on with my task). I will also attach a screenshot of my file explorer. [image: File explorer screenshot]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

void check(FILE*);

int main()
{

    FILE *fp1;
    char ch, a;

    fp1 = fopen("A00924956Results2016", "r");
    check(fp1);

    fscanf(fp1, "%c", &a);
    printf("First character is %c", a);

    fclose(fp1);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
void check(FILE *fp1)
{
    fp1 = fopen("A00924956Results2016.dat", "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not accessing file properly\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling and keeping the executable file in the same directory?
Also, in the `check()` method, only check if the argument fp1 is null or not. Don't try to open a file again.

Comment: Try `fp1 = fopen("A00924956Results2016.txt", "r");` (Windows by default hides known extensions) and what are you trying to do with this: `fp1 = fopen("A00924956Results2016.dat", "r");`? Remove that and try the former.

Comment: Also, when posting such questions, please shorten the code as much as possible. Remove all the irrelevant stuff out of the code. Always try to make a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry will do next time. The .dat is a mistake. I changed both to .txt and it still says that it cant access the file!!

Comment: Please fix up your question to show your latest code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the file you are trying to open is a text document. so while using fopen() function, use need to use .txt extension with the file name to open it properly. 
I think it will work properly if you add .txt at the end of file name while opening it.

Answer (score 0):

In the fopen() function you need to write the whole file name with extension like "**A00924956Results2016.txt**" instead of just "A00924956Results2016".